# Excel fill rows base from data from different tab

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an issue that I can't think of a solution using formula and I am also not sure if formula would work.

Let's say this is my Sheet1

[image]

And here is my Sheet2

[image]

What I want is that in Sheet1, the ingredients fields from A10-A11 should be filled by the ingredients of what I enter in Food field A2, something like this:

[image]

Let's say I input another entry in Food field, the output should be like this:

[image]

And say I removed the first entry in Food field:

[image]

Is it possible to do something like this with just formula? If yes, can you help me how?

I've been searching and I really can't imagine any way that uses formula. I thought of using HLOOKUP and VLOOKUP but it's not what is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use REDUCE, FILTER and VSTACK:

```
=DROP(REDUCE("",FILTER(A2:A8,A2:A8<>""),LAMBDA(z,y,VSTACK(z,FILTER(F:F,E:E=y)))),1)
```

[image]

[image]

---

***For older versions:***

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(F:F,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($F$2:$F$5)/ISNUMBER(MATCH($E$2:$E$5,$A$2:$A$8,0)),ROW(A1))),"")
```

Put that in A10 and copy it down far enough to cover all possible returns.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick and correct reply Scott, but I am using Excel 2016 and Filter is not working. Is there any alternative for FILTER function?

Comment: And you should specify the version need.

Comment: Cool Sir, I was doing the other way round using `MATCH()=ROW()-ROW()+1` so it was becoming difficult, thanks completely forgotten abt `ISNUMBER()` thanks again!

Comment: Sir isntead of `ISNUMBER()` you can use `1-ISNA(MATCH(` it will be shorter --> `=IFERROR(INDEX(F:F,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($F$2:$F$5)/(1-ISNA(MATCH($E$2:$E$5,$A$2:$A$8,0))),ROW(A1))),"")`

Comment: I prefer the ISNUMBER because it is easier to read and understand, while I know `1-ISNA` is the same as `NOT(ISNA(` but for the casual looker it takes a moment longer to translate.  ISNUMBER is immediately recognizable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `TOCOL()` & `IFS()`

[image]

---

```
=TOCOL(IFS(TOROW(A2:A3)=C2:C5,D2:D5),2)
```

---

Comment: see the comment below mine.  OP does not have office 365, they are using 2016  Neither answer will work for them.

Comment: But nice use of a 2D array.

Comment: @ScottCraner Sir, oh no. Ok Sir, i will try with `INDEX()` & `AGGREGATE()` then. Sir i cant vote comments, its all consumed. will do later. Thank you very much Sir, looks like its not that easy with `INDEX()` & `AGGREGATE()` as well

Comment: Great idea on Index/Agg see my edit.

Comment: By sheer chance, the result is as expected because the order in column `A` is the same as the order in column `C`. Squeeze in a `,1` (you know where) to scan by column.

Comment: @VBasic2008, I am newbie to excel, can you explain where to put the ,1?

Comment: @hanz you don't have access to `MS365` and he is saying related to the solution I have posted. Its after `2` in `TOCOL()` for by columns.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, I am trying this formula in google spreadsheet to check because I'm curious. It is not working

Comment: @hanz your question is not related with google sheets. so its pointless to try. And the formula is working solution for `Excel`

Comment: @hanz for `Google Sheets` it needs to be wrapped within `ARRAYFORMULA()` --> Could try : `=TOCOL(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(TOROW(A2:A3)=C2:C5,D2:D5,NA())),2)` **[Refer Screenshot](https://imgur.com/gallery/HfaYRug)**

Comment: @hanz yes I know it will work 